# protocols delegate methods not calling properly in ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, protocols

Hi i am very new for ios  and in my project i am using web services ok that's fine

and in my mainView controller i have added one button when i tapped on it i am calling services using post method
and i am getting response also very quickly from my server

Here my main problem is i am calling my services from my background class and for this i am using here protocols for getting response from services and total response i have stored in my array list

And when array list count is "0"  i just show one alert message and when it's having records i am push to another view controller as like my below code

but when we enter below my else block then quickly it's not moving(i mean pushing) to my DetailsClass why what is the problem here can any body help me please

### my code:-

```
- (IBAction)details:(id)sender {

  NSDictionary *mainDictionary = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                    @"1234",@"scancode" ,
                                    nil];
 [BP postServieCalling:@"myurl here" :mainDictionary];

}

//Protocol method for getting response from services

- (void) PostCallService: (NSMutableArray*)mainDictyionary{

    NSLog(@"final response here %@",mainDictyionary);

    if (mainDictyionary.count == 0) {

         NSLog(@" if block");

    }else{
         NSLog(@" else block");
        DetailsClass *details = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsClass"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you get response from web service that response is not in main thread.All UI operation should be perform in main thread. there for put your else block in main thread using below code.

```
//  For Objective c

dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    DetailsClass *details = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsClass"];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
});
```

-

```
// For Swift 

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        DetailsClass *details = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DetailsClass"];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:details animated:YES];
    }
```

Comment: In your else condition

Comment: dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() in this line showing errors when i paste your code in my else block

Comment: i am very new for this technology please explain clealrly, i mean please write that line with full code

Comment: are you working in swift or objective c, check my both answer.

Comment: i am getting response from server very quickly using post method

but can we make server wait 1 minute for getting response?

Comment: That is need to manage by server using some sleep command to hold process. But my suggestion is not to do this kind of thing. Getting response quickly is good thing.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99175/discussion-between-abhiram-and-crazy-developer).